# Prevent GridView reset scroll to top when element is tapped?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView that is populated by all apps installed on the device. The user can select certain apps here. I want the selected apps to be opaque and non-selected to be partially transparent. I did this with the following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsText = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 90);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    TextView appLabel = new TextView(mContext);
    final OurAppInfo info = (OurAppInfo) getItem(position);

    if(!installedApplications.contains(info)){
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.4F, 0.4F);
        alpha.setDuration(0);
        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
        linearLayout.startAnimation(alpha);
    }

    String appName = info.label;
    if (appName.length() > 25) {
        appName = appName.substring(0, 25);
        appName = appName + "...";
    }
    appLabel.setText(appName);
    appLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    appLabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    appLabel.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    imageView.setImageDrawable(info.drawableAppIcon);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(110, 110));
    appLabel.setTextSize(15);

    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (installedApplications.contains(info)){
                installedApplications.remove(info);
                receiveUpdate(installedApplications, false, false);
            } else {
                installedApplications.add(info);
                Collections.sort(installedApplications);
                receiveUpdate(installedApplications, false, false);
            }
        }
    });

    appLabel.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsText);

    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    linearLayout.addView(appLabel);

    return linearLayout;
}
```

This is part of the `GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter`. The code works as expected, when I tap on an app it is either removed from or added to the list and according to transparency is set. However, whenever I tap on an element in the GridView, the view is reset and I am brought to the top of the scrollable GridView. Obviously, this isn't a problem for a small number of apps, but if you're selecting apps near the XYZ letters, every time you select one you are brought back to ABC. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're refreshing the adapter whenever you make changes that makes the grid go back to initial position. You could try saving and restoring the position before making any changes to the adapter.

```
//Before refreshing the adapter you get both X and Y position
int xPos = grid.getScrollX();
int yPos = grid.getScrollY();
```

Then you update your adapter.

After the adapter is recreated you restore the grid position:

```
grid.scrollTo(xPos, yPos);
```

You could also use (everytime possible) the method **notifyDataSetChanged()** instead of creating a new adapter.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check all child views for automatic height or width.
I guess gridview calculates size of this views whenever you change data.
This was solution in my case.

In my case changed this:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

To this:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp" />
```